Ethernet not working on Ubuntu through the main router
I set up a PC about a month ago and put Ubuntu on it to host a Minecraft server. It's been running excellently, but one night I opened my router's webpage and opened the port that Minecraft uses and gave the server a static IP address. I made those changes late at night, so I went to bed instead and figured I would try it the next morning. When I woke up I noticed the server didn’t have any Ethernet.
After many days of troubleshooting I have restarted my router a number of times, reset all the changes back to default. I even reinstalled Ubuntu and cleared the CMOS, but when I plug it into my router I get the internet icon with the three dots on Ubuntu and it says at the top "failed to initiate internet connect" or something along those lines.
What confuses me is not only does every other device still work fine even when plugged in, but I have eero network boosters and when I plug the server into one of those it gets Ethernet fine. For server reasons I need it plugged into the main router and can’t seem to figure out what’s going on. I have reset about
all that I can reset at this point with no luck.
Edit: the router keeps adding del in the comments field. Idk what that means and when I get rid of it and press save, it just adds it back.

The problem is with the router as you have said in your question. Contact the ISP and get a new router.

I’m not dismissing your response but wouldn’t that affect other devices as well? I plugged another computer with similar hardware but with windows into the router and it get Ethernet as well as a laptop that also worked fine

If it is Gnome Network manager did not detect 5GHz wifi. Installing MATE desktop environment resolve this.

I’m plugging the server directly into the router via Ethernet and through the routers webpage the device shows up. When you look at Ubuntu it doesn’t connect and it says it failed to initiate. No other devices are having this issue but ubuntu was reinstalled and even shows up as a new device through the routers web interface. When the server is plugged into another source of Ethernet it works.

Is it possible that the Ubuntu machine is requesting a DHCP lease, but the router still has its MAC listed as reserved for static assignment?

I changed the MAC address of the new machine to make sure it showed up as a new machine to the router. The router shows it as a new machine and even shows it as connected but when you look on Ubuntu it says it didn’t connect

Nevermind. Although the changed worked yesterday. It now shows up as the same devices as it originally was. Despite that reinstall of ubuntu
